# How to pass object by reference to function and access variables inside public struct

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm just wondering if it is possible to do something like this below? Right now in the `itemModifier` function, I am passing in each struct item individually from the range based for loop. Right now this is okay, however as I suspect the function paramters will grow I don't want to have one giant function that takes 8 variables and would instead rather pass the object by reference and access the `a` and `b` variables directly as opposed to making a copy of them.

```c++
class Items
{
public:
    struct lastItems
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
    
public:
    bool itemModifier(Items &items)
    vector<lastItems> getItems();    // just returns lastItems 
};

bool Items::itemModifier(Items &items)
{
    std::cout << items.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << items.b << std::endl;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    Items items;

    /* Read file supplied in that populates a and b 
       and adds it to vector<lastItems>              */

    for(auto &i:items){
        item.itemModifier(i);
    }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
``
```

Comment: well, class `Items` doesn't have any data. Did you mean to add `private:
 vector<lastItems> li;`

Comment: *"I'm just wondering if it is possible to do something like this below?"* -- Considering that "this below" exists, I conclude that, yes, it is possible. Perhaps you could describe what you are trying to accomplish in words before throwing us at the code?

Comment: Why not pass a `struct` that contains the other variables as an argument?   You have options of passing that `struct` by reference and/or for that `struct` to contain members that are references (initialised so they refer to your chosen variables).   If you don't want to pass *any* additional arguments, you'll be limited to either modifying `Items` so it contains a reference, or (an option with lots of down sides) storing the additional variables in globals